# INT more than 2147483647 always turn to 2147483647 in PHP

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5.4

My DB id is more than 2147483647 (integer), so if I get that ID turns to 2147483647 when I convert my data to Json.

This is my json result

```
[
    {"id":2147483647, "district_id":7171051, "name":"KARAME"},
    {"id":2147483647, "district_id":7171051, "name":"KETANG BARU"},
    {"id":2147483647, "district_id":7171051, "name":"WAWONASA"},
    {"id":2147483647, "district_id":7171051, "name":"TERNATE BARU"},
    {"id":2147483647, "district_id":7171051, "name":"TERNATE TANJUNG"},
    {"id":2147483647, "district_id":7171051, "name":"KOMBOS BARAT"},
    {"id":2147483647, "district_id":7171051, "name":"KOMBOS TIMUR"},
    {"id":2147483647, "district_id":7171051, "name":"SINGKIL SATU"},
    {"id":2147483647, "district_id":7171051, "name":"SINGKIL DUA"}
]
```

My actual data are

```
[
    {"id":7171051001, "district_id":7171051, "name":"KARAME"},
    {"id":7171051002, "district_id":7171051, "name":"KETANG BARU"},
    {"id":7171051003, "district_id":7171051, "name":"WAWONASA"},
    {"id":7171051004, "district_id":7171051, "name":"TERNATE BARU"},
    {"id":7171051005, "district_id":7171051, "name":"TERNATE TANJUNG"},
    {"id":7171051006, "district_id":7171051, "name":"KOMBOS BARAT"},
    {"id":7171051007, "district_id":7171051, "name":"KOMBOS TIMUR"},
    {"id":7171051008, "district_id":7171051, "name":"SINGKIL SATU"},
    {"id":7171051009, "district_id":7171051, "name":"SINGKIL DUA"}
]
```

I am using Laravel 5.4
How to make it to my actual ID?
Thanks.

Comment: It's very difficult to copy-and-paste your images into a text editor in order to verify your results. Please replace the embedded images with `formatted text`. And include the source code you're using to process the data and generate those results.

Comment: It sounds like you're running 32bit PHP and/or on 32bit hardware, so you're hitting the maximum integer size. You'll need to look into 64bit hardware and 64bit PHP version.

Comment: It's definitely because you're casting to an int from your initial string on 32-bit hardware.

Comment: If the column is integer, you could try using bigint. If you don't need to treat it as an integer, you can store it as a string. But I thought that it would overflow instead of becoming fixed like that

Comment: I am running 32-bit so I change to 64-bit then it works. thank you @fubar ishegg Qirel

Comment: Sure, I'll using formatted text next time @ghoti

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP, you can't have integer bigger than `PHP_INT_MAX`, which in 32-bit hardware (or 32-bit PHP) is `2147483647 = 2^31-1`, which is the number you're getting (for reference, in 64-bit it's `9223372036854775807 = 2^63-1`). And, your original data, wherever you're getting it from, has the ID as a string (notice the quotes around them).

So, when you cast it to an integer, it gets truncated to `2147483647`. Now, you have two options:

- Upgrade your hardware/PHP version to 64-bit. Then, though, as mentioned, you will still have the `9223372036854775807` limit, which is obviously much higher.
- If you aren't doing any arithmetics with your IDs, you *could* just keep them as a string. There's nothing wrong with an alphanumeric ID. In this case, though, you'd have to be careful to treat it as a string along your entire stack.

Answer (score 2):

Integer values more then 2147483647 available in PHP on 64x-bit platforms. If you using 32x bit platform, you have limit on max integer value. 
Another reason of this trouble is PHP_INT_SIZE var in your php configuration (php.ini).

Json does not matter.

You can read more http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php